# How do I disable the Microsoft Edge search bar on the Windows desktop?

Tags: windows-10, search, desktop, microsoft-edge

On Windows 10, recently a Microsoft Edge search bar started appearing on the desktop.

[image]

If you click the 3 dots menu there is an option to "Auto-launch search bar" which you can turn off and then close the bar.  One would think this would disable it, but on restart the search bar comes back.

[image]

How can I disable this desktop search bar so it doesn't appear even after a reboot?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can disable the search bar by making a registry edit.  So far I haven't found a way to turn this off without making a registry edit (there are some old tutorials about a pop-up dialog appearing that would allow turning it off permanently but that dialog no longer seems to appear)

The [`WebWidgetAllowed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#webwidgetallowed) value controls this.

Open regedit. The `WebWidgetAllowed` key is located at `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge`

For me the `Edge` folder and key didn't exist, so I needed to go to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft` right click on Microsoft folder and choose `New -> Key`, and then type `Edge`.

Then I right-clicked on the `Edge` folder I just created and chose `New -> DWORD (32-bit) Value` and typed `WebWidgetAllowed` for the name.  The default value is `0` which is false so I didn't need to change that.

Then saved and closed regedit and rebooted and the desktop search bar no longer appears.